# Calendar editing

Tags: permissions

Does Sharepoint have a permission setting that will allow only a user to add to a calendar/site and edit only their additions to the the calendar/site and is will not allow  editing of anyone elses?
If so can you provide steps...

Answer (score 0):

Go into the List settings and click on the Advanced Settings link. Set the Item Level Permissions to Create items and edit items that were created by the user for the Create and edit portion of the question.